# Tabularx In beamer is not fitting in frame

Tags: beamer, lyx, tabularx

I am having a problem with the tabularx environment in beamer which is that my columns are being squished together. I am a bit new to using beamer so would someone please provide some advice ?

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}l<{\end{lrbox}}@{}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
    \begin{document}
\documentclass{beamer}


    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYYYYYY @{}}   

    \toprule   

\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}} \\

    \midrule   

    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\   
                                & TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace  
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 15.80 & 0.00 \\
    & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 8.96 & 5.07 & -0.57 & -9.38 & 0.00 \\
    & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 10.13 & 5.19 & -0.44 & 10.87 & 0.00\\

    & Top minus Bottom & 3.75 & 6.54 & 2.45 & 18.54 & 0.00\\ 

    \addlinespace

    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 11.76 & 8.73 & 0.1915 & 14.62 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 8.38 & 5.76 & -0.59 & 8.74 & 0.00 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 3.38 & 5.94 & 0.68 & 11.03 & 0.00 \\
    & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 11.79 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.00 \\
    & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 10.04 & 5.64 & 0.03 & 13.76 & 0.00 \\
    & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 9.04 & 5.43 & -0.73 & 8.80 & 0.00 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 2.72 & 5.60 & 0.82 & 12.79 & 0.00 \\   

\bottomrule 

\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The picture below is as follows:

[image]

As can be seen, I am having some large issues and would really like some help given that I have tried to use \adjustbox but that didnt really work as the column height got expanded but not the width. If someone has a solution or could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `shrink` frame option:

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=40]

\end{frame}
```

**Complete Example:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{G}{@{}>{\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}}l<{\end{lrbox}}@{}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{\RaggedRight}X }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{Y}{ >{\Centering}X}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage[round,sort,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bmpsize}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=40]
    \vspace*{2em}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} lYYYYYY @{}}   

    \toprule   

\thead[lc]{Category }& \thead{Strategies}& {\thead{Annualized \\ Mean}} & {\thead{Volatility}} & {\thead{Skew}} & {\thead{kurtosis}} & {\thead{Sharpe \\ Ratio}} \\

    \midrule   

    \multirow{2}{*}{ Momentum } & TSMOM(1,1) & 3.18 &  3.84 & -0.26 & 20.06 & 0.00  \\   
                                & TSMOM(3,3) & 11.85 &  7.76 & -1.96 & 24.72 & 0.00  \\ \addlinespace  
    \multirow{5}{*}{ Size } & Top Decile & 12.70 & 9.26 & 1.44 & 15.80 & 0.00 \\
    & 9\textsuperscript{th} Decile & 0.11 & 8.49 & 0.49 & 12.73 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 8.96 & 5.07 & -0.57 & -9.38 & 0.00 \\
    & 2\textsuperscript{nd} Decile & 10.13 & 5.19 & -0.44 & 10.87 & 0.00\\

    & Top minus Bottom & 3.75 & 6.54 & 2.45 & 18.54 & 0.00\\ 

    \addlinespace

    \multirow{7}{*}{ Value } & Top Decile & 11.76 & 8.73 & 0.1915 & 14.62 & 0.00\\
    & Bottom Decile & 8.38 & 5.76 & -0.59 & 8.74 & 0.00 \\
    & Top Minus Lowest (Decile) & 3.38 & 5.94 & 0.68 & 11.03 & 0.00 \\
    & Top 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 11.79 & 8.73 & 0.19 & 14.62 & 0.00 \\
    & Mid 40\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 10.04 & 5.64 & 0.03 & 13.76 & 0.00 \\
    & Bottom 30\textsuperscript{th} Percentile & 9.04 & 5.43 & -0.73 & 8.80 & 0.00 \\
    & Highest Minus Lowest 30\textsuperscript{th} & 2.72 & 5.60 & 0.82 & 12.79 & 0.00 \\   

\bottomrule 

\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how i would be able to add a title to the frame ? It seems that keeping the [shrink=40] removes the title from the frame

Comment: Actually `\begin{frame}[shrink=40]{Title}` should work.